# How can i read CSV file in pandas with Nan?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a txt file:

```
24688 1965 12 31 12   0  0    0.0 -48.3
24688 1965 12 31 15   0  0        -47.2
24688 1965 12 31 18   0  0        -49.0
24688 1965 12 31 21   0  0    0.0 -48.1
24688 1966  1  1  0   0  0    0.0 -52.5
```

..........

I'm trying to get this DataFrame used 
`data = pd.read_csv('/home/igor/py/normdata.txt', header=None, sep='\s+')`

```
24688 1965 12 31 12   0  0    0.0 -48.3
24688 1965 12 31 15   0  0    Nan -47.2
24688 1965 12 31 18   0  0    Nan -49.0
24688 1965 12 31 21   0  0    0.0 -48.1
24688 1966  1  1  0   0  0    0.0 -52.5
```

But i get:

```
24688   1965    12  31  12  0.0 0.0 0.0 -48.3
24688   1965    12  31  15  0.0 0.0 -47.2 Nan
24688   1965    12  31  18  0.0 0.0 -49.0 Nan
24688   1965    12  31  21  0.0 0.0 0.0 -48.1
24688   1966    1   1   0   0.0 0.0 0.0 -52.5
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 4):

You should tell Pandas that the separator consists of up to four spaces:

```
pd.read_csv('/home/igor/py/normdata.txt', sep="\s{1,4}", 
            header=None)
```

You may also consider using `pandas.read_fwf()` because your table has fixed-width format.